# Font Weight Bug React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently facing a font weight issue. This occured after I installed a custom font via Xcode. I've linked everything and the custom font works but I still see no effect?

```
attrName: {
   color: '#000',
   fontWeight: '300' /* Normally this should work */
},
```

Has anyone else stumbled upon this issue? Need to solve this fast...

**UPDATE**

I solved this a while after posting this. If you want different font weights to your text element, make sure to import all types of weight of your font in Xcode or Android Studio. One weight or version of the font is not enough...

Comment: I also got a similar issue. `fontWeight` does not work as I expected. Let's say it has no effect until 500 and from 600 upwards it gets bold. However I expect it to be gradual.

Comment: Exactly! But why does this happen? It's really annoying xd

Answer (score 8):

I'm facing a similar issue.

- react: 16.0.0-alpha.6
- react-native:  0.44

`fontWeight: '300'` works for IOS but doesn't for Android. I certainly don't want to include ALL font weights for every single font I use, that's why I propose the following approach for those who are still looking:

```
// Style definition
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    base: {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    },
    light: {
        ...Platform.select({
            ios: {
                fontWeight: '300',
            },
            android: {
                // RN 0.44.0 bug: fontWeight 300 not linked to *Thin or *Light fonts yet...
                fontFamily: 'Roboto-Thin',
            },
        }),
    },
});
```

Usage example:

```
<Text style={styles.base}>Hello world</Text>
<Text style={[styles.base, styles.light]}>Hello light world</Text>
```

In future releases, this will most likely be fixed by the API, but the devs have got their hands full for now :)

Answer (score -3):

I was facing the same issue, but the I realized that is should be -
`fontWeight:'bold',`
not -
`fontweight:'bold',`

the only difference is **w->W**

ya some time we get wrong auto suggestion, usually happens a lot when you work on lot of different languages.